# ArcPy: Selecting feature class by attribute then copy selection to new feature class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, copy

Using ArcPy I want to make to do a selection on a feature class by field to select everything 0.1 or greater, then copy the selection to a new feature class.

However, the output of my following code is exactly the same as the input and includes values under 0.1.

```
input_fc = r"C:\Geoprocessing\Model.gdb\input_fc"
output_fc = r"C:\Geoprocessing\Model.gdb\output_fc"

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=input_fc, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause="Field1 >= 0.1")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(input_fc, output_fc)
```

is there a step I am missing?

Comment: Sure is. You need to make a layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the coding pattern that I would use do that:

```
input_fc = r"C:\Geoprocessing\Model.gdb\input_fc"
output_fc = r"C:\Geoprocessing\Model.gdb\output_fc"

arcpy.Select_analysis(input_fc, output_fc, where_clause="Field1 >= 0.1")
```